# Java execute method from within a loop every few seconds

Tags: java

I have a Thread that runs in my test app with a while loop inside the thread. While the while loop is running i want to execute a method from within this while loop every 30 seconds. Inside the while loop, don't want to sleep the thread or stop the loop, it must run and every 30 seconds call the method.

```
 Thread myThread = new Thread() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        //my code that runs with a loop
        //while loop here that runs and needs to execute method every 30 seconds, if condition met continue else break;
     };
     myThread.start();
 }
```

Comment: You mean, you need the Thread to `sleep()`?

Comment: no, just need to execute the method within the while loop every 30 seconds, if the condition the method returns is not met it will stop the loop, if it is met the loop will continue.

Comment: if you want to sleep for 30 seconds use gameLatencyThread.sleep(30*1000)

Comment: what I meant was while the loop is running I want to call a method every 30 seconds from within that loop.

Comment: You want to execute the while and method in the same moment? in two different threads? Or you want to execute the method inside the while which is executed every 30 secs?

Comment: While the while loop is running i want to execute a method from within this while loop every 30 seconds. Inside the while loop, don't want to sleep the thread or stop the loop, it must run and every 30 seconds call the method.

Comment: I think you don't understand how things works... the while execute the method then it will be paused for 30 seconds and after it will reexecute the method. The sleep is used to pause the thread(the while loop) for 30 seconds to avoid to call the method every x ms.

Comment: I do understand how it works, maybe my question is confusing. the while loop will run and do whatever while a condition is true, just an example it will continue to print hello, but every 30 seconds I want to call a method to and use the return value as a condition, if the condition is met the while will still continue to run and print hello (millions of hellos by now), if not met exit the loop.

Comment: OOh, ok! Then as @PaulRichter said you use a timestamp to check if passed 30 seconds o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To wait, you can use

```
Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
```

For documentation, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

If you wait for 30 seconds in your loop, it happens every 30 seconds + execution time of your function. As long as your function call only takes milliseconds this is as precise as doing it in a more complex way.

If you want your loop to keep running but you do not want to launch a new `Thread`, you can use [the current Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29):

```
long lastCall = 0;

while(bla) {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCall > 30000) {
        lastCall = System.currentTimeMillis();
        callTheFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, don't want to sleep the thread and execute the while every 30 seconds, what I meant was while the loop is running I want to call a method every 30 seconds from within that loop.

Comment: @user3523456 I am not sure what you want, you can take the current time everytime in your loop and save the last time you called. The if currentTime-lastTime is >30 seconds you call. But I see no reason why you should not just start a new Thread

Comment: what your saying about taking the current time everytime and compare it to last time called makes sense, how would I execute something like this?

Comment: @user3523456 see edit :) edit: fixed typos. notify me if you need more details

Comment: it works perfect, My loop runs and every 30 seconds I call my method and it return a value, that value is then based on the condition of whether the loop should continue or not and works perfectly. thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

Place it where thread is executed:

```
Thread.sleep(30000);
```

Comment: While the while loop is running i want to execute a method from within this while loop every 30 seconds. Inside the while loop, don't want to sleep the thread or stop the loop, it must run and every 30 seconds call the method.