# How to run code inside for loop every 5 seconds in java?

Tags: java

I want to execute specific code located inside for loop every 5 seconds.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check Thread.sleep()

Comment: But thread.sleep() will delay the loop itself, and I don't want to delay it... I just want to execute a code inside loops every 5 seconds

Comment: Check ScheduledExecutorService

Answer (score 0):

In that case, a `java.util.Timer` would be a more fitting solution.
A timer allows you to execute a function every x milliseconds.
Though, you'll have to define and call the timer outside of the loop.

Alternatively, you can check out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013560/java-execute-method-from-within-a-loop-every-few-seconds) that @Filburt has suggested to see in which you can use the current time to execute a code within a loop every x seconds.

If you still want to go with the timer solution, here's how you set it:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                // code to execute
            }
}, MILLISECONDS); // replace MILLISECONDS with the amount of milliseconds between each execution.
```

Note that the timer itself doesn't know when to stop. You can create a field in the anonymous class that counts each execution and cancels the timer when reaching a specific number:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int times = 0;

            @Override
            public void run () {
                if (times == 5) { // replace 5 with the amount of times you want the code executed.
                   timer.cancel();
                   return;
                }
                // code to execute
                times++;
            }
}, MILLISECONDS);
```